# Can we use like this <body class="all" <!--[if IE 7]>class="ie"<![endif]--> >

Tags: css, xhtml, conditional-comments

Can we use like this `<body class="all" <!--[if IE 7]>class="ie"<![endif]--> >`?

I want to keep all CSS in one file.

Comment: Ricebowl's solution of an IE only div is the best way to capture what you want if you are determined to have one CSS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
<body class="all">
  <!--[if ie]>
    <div class="ieOnly">
  <![endif]-->

<div id="content">

<p>...</p>

</div>

  <!--[if ie]>
    </div>
  <![endif]-->
</body>
```

That way the css selector to address IE's flaws/differences is more specific than the normal

```
#content {/* for non-IE browsers */}

body.all .ieOnly #content {/* for IE */}
```

...and should override the 'normal' `#content` rules and will never be applied by non-IE browsers, since there's an element `.ieOnly` in the selector which is otherwise 'invisible' to them.

Still, strictly speaking, no; you can't do what you propose in your question, though there are alternative approaches.

Comment: Clever idea to use IE tags in body, not just on the style declarations.

Comment: It allows for perfectly valid css, in a single stylesheet, the html is also valid, depending on your views on IE conditional comments. But yeah, it should validate fine.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: what? No. It's **never** valid to have more than one `body` tag inside a (x)html document*. Have I led you to think it might be? (* Unless the subsequent `body` tags are within frames/iframes and the parent document has an appropriate doctype.)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No** (at least, not in-line), but why do you need to? :)

Just defined a `body { }` style in an IE conditional stylesheet, like this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

And inside there:

```
body { /* or body.all { */
  background: pink; /* Pink is pretty!, or green, whatever */
}
```

Comment: I want to keep all style in one css.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - You place this after your main CSS, whatever styles are in it's `body` declaration will override previously defined properties (barring `!important`), just like any other CSS would.  For this part "I want to keep all style in one css"...well, you can't have *valid* CSS and do IE specific styling then, you'll have to use hacky CSS, which I advise against.

Comment: Darn, Nick... give the rest of us a chance... ;) Why don't you get married or something?! (went to your site the other day... All the best to you two!)

Comment: @Gert - You'll see a flat-line in my activity graph around mid-September ;)

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: You ought to separate the IE specific styles or you'll get a maintenance nightmare. :)

Comment: Agree with Gert G, but if there's only one or two and you don't want to server-side merge your CSS file you can probably get away with a heavily notated "THIS IS FOR IE" section in your CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant specifically comment out an attribute even with IE's conditional comments. But there could be other ways of expressing it.

Comment: instead of using conditional commnet and different css and css hacks i wanted to add a class to body then i can use that class for all IE specfic CSS needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a class to body based on the browser without hacks, you're gonna need to use server-side code and UA sniffing.